# Prove that if $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$, then $H$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Would someone please help me:

Question : Let $φ : G → H$ be an isomorphism of two groups. Then prove that if $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$, then $H$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

Proof :  For the case that subgroup is group also, $φ(g)^n=φ(g^n)$ and $|G|=|H|$ solves the problem. For general case, i.e. proper subgroup I have no idea.

Comment: Let $K$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $n$, then show that $\varphi(K)$ is a subgroup of $H$ of order $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $I$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\varphi(I)$ (the image of $I$ under $\varphi$) is a subgroup of $H$, which is easy to show (use the definition of isomorphism). And as $\varphi$ is an isomorphism $\varphi(I)$ has the same cardinality as $I$.

Answer (score 2):

You can show this explicitly by restricting the isomorphism to a subgroup.

Let $K$ be a subgroup of $G$ with $|K|=n$.

First, you can show that a homomorphism maps subgroups to subgroups. To show that $\varphi(K)$ is a subgroup, you need to show the following:

- The identity of $\varphi'(K)$ is $\varphi'(1)$, where $1$ is the identity of $K$.
- It is has closure: $\varphi(k_1), \varphi(k_1) \in \varphi(K) \implies \varphi(k_1)\varphi(k_2) \in \varphi(K)$
- It has inverses: $\varphi(k)^{-1} = \varphi(k^{-1}) \in \varphi(K)$

All these follow from the facts that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism and $K$ is a subgroup.

---

Now consider the restriction $\varphi'$ of $\varphi$ to $K$; we want to show that $\varphi': K \to \varphi(K)$ is an isomorphism.

- It is a homomorphism because $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.
- It is clearly surjective.
- $\ker\varphi' \subseteq \ker\varphi = \{1\}$, so $\ker\varphi'=\{1\}$ too, meaning it is injective.

Hence, it is an isomorphism, and  $|K|=|\varphi(K)|$.

Comment: It would be good to mention something about why $\phi(K)$ is even a group.

Comment: @KyleMiller I can add that. Thanks.